# If$ (x-a)^2=(x+a)^2$ for all values of $x$, then what is the value of a?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

If $(x-a)^2=(x+a)^2$ for all values of $x$, then what is the value of $a$? Please help, thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried to expand both sides yet?

Comment: Welcome to Math. SE. When you ask a question here, please show your efforts. In this case if you expand both sides, you will get the answer

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What happens if you choose $x=a$?

Comment: I was just about to post an almost identical answer! +1

Comment: @CameronWilliams "Do **not** expand" was screaming through my brain. Had to let it out ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand the quadratic terms and eliminate like terms.